# Dictionary Comprehension example

Tags: python, dictionary, set, dictionary-comprehension

I have a set, which contains n sets of prime numbers(3):

```
>>> sets
{frozenset({3, 13, 23}), frozenset({17, 2, 13}), 
frozenset({19, 2, 3}), frozenset({3, 29, 23}), frozenset({17, 11, 23}),
frozenset({17, 2, 19}), frozenset({11, 17, 3}), frozenset({17, 5, 7})}
```

I want to create the dictionary with values: prime numbers-triple and keys: the product of three prime numbers.

This is my attempt:

```
lists = [list(i) for i in sets]
products = [reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,i) for i in lists]
dictir = {x:y for x in products for y in sets}
```

But dictir gives me incorrect result:

```
{897: frozenset({17, 5, 7}), 114: frozenset({17, 5, 7}), 595: frozenset({17, 5, 7}), 561: frozenset({17, 5, 7}), 646: frozenset({17, 5, 7}), 2001: frozenset({17, 5, 7}), 442: frozenset({17, 5, 7}), 4301: frozenset({17, 5, 7})}
```

Can you help me to correct this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may use `zip()` but another, more efficient approach would be this:

```
import operator
tuples = ((reduce(operator.mul, i), i) for i in sets)
dictir = dict(tuples)

# Or as a 1 liner
dictir = {reduce(operator.mul, i): i for i in sets}
```

Comment: it gives me "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: @YNWA1992 Fixed and tested.

Answer (score 0):

You do double iteration and effectively create Cartesian product of `lists` and `products`.

To iterate elementwise on multiple sequences simply use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
dictir = {x: y for x, y in zip(products, sets)}
```

Of course you may drop all intermediate variables and do simple one-liner:

```
sets = {frozenset({3, 13, 23}), frozenset({17, 2, 13}),
        frozenset({19, 2, 3}), frozenset({3, 29, 23}), frozenset({17, 11, 23}),
        frozenset({17, 2, 19}), frozenset({11, 17, 3}), frozenset({17, 5, 7})}
dictir = {reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, s): s for s in sets}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, you can simply use that:

```
import operator
dictir = {reduce(operator.mul,numbers):numbers for value in sets}
```